# How to add support for 10.5 inch iPad Pro

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios10, ios11

I've just downloaded the latest Xcode 8.3.3 update from the MAS. **I was wondering how to add support for the new 10.5-inch iPad Pro?**

I'm using storyboards with auto-layout, a launch screen storyboard and all app icon sizes are added to the xcassets.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe that the auto-layout launch screen story board should be all that is needed. However, I have found that if I build an application under Xcode 8.3.3, the UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds returns 736 x 1024. If I build the same application under Xcode 9 and the iOS 11 SDK beta, UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds returns 834 x 1112.

UPDATE:
As others have mentioned, when an app is built with Xcode 8.3.3/iOS 10.3 and is running on the iPad Pro 10.5 simulator, the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key in the app info.list determines whether or not the app is scaled to 768 x 1024. **If `UIRequiresFullScreen` = YES, the app is scaled. If `UIRequiresFullScreen` = NO, the app is full resolution (834 x 1112).**
However, if the app is built with Xcode 9/iOS 11 beta 1, it always runs at the full native resolution regardless of the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key setting. Some developers believe that this is intentional behavior and not a bug. Others believe it is simply an artifact of running the iOS 10 app under the iOS 11 simulator. We probably won't know for sure until developers receive the new hardware.

Comment: I think it is a bug or missing configuration. I even tried editing the launch storyboard in 8.3.3 to see if that would change anything.

Comment: I just filed Radar 32604743

Comment: According to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78680 (where David Dunham seems to have been!), apps that set UIRequiresFullScreen in the Info.plist will run at 1024x768pt on the 10.5". If there's a Launch screen storyboard then the 12.9" iPad Pro will run at full resolution (1366x1024pt). I suspect this may be a deliberate backward compatibility feature because nobody's app is expecting the new size. Build with Xcode 9 and you opt in.

Comment: Along with setting `UIRequiresFullScreen` to false, you'll also need to set `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` or `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` to support all 4 orientations.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround for now seems to be to go back to using individual launch images rather than a launch screen storyboard.

([This thread on Twitter](https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/879021146833813504) had the answer. Also I took a look at the `Info.plist` file for [Linea](http://linea-app.com), and that seems to be exactly how they've achieved it).

[image: Linea's Info.plist file]