# Run the application in iPad 10.5 inch Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have downloaded Xcode 8.3.3 and I am able to view iPad pro 10.5 inch in Interface builder. But I would like to test it in iPad pro 10.5 inch simulator. Is there anyway to download that simulator on Xcode.

I have looked at below thread but it does not answer my question.

[How to add support for 10.5 inch iPad Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392646/how-to-add-support-for-10-5-inch-ipad-pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to download a different simulator for different device sizes, only for different iOS versions. Look for "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)" in the Xcode "Devices" window (press Shift+Cmd+2 to show it). If it's not there, try using the "+" button to add it.

Also make sure your target is correctly set up. Click on your project in the file navigator and select the target you're building in the main pane, then:

1. look in the deployment info for your target (in your target's "General" tab) and make sure "Devices" are set to "Universal" or "iPad",
2. make sure the Base SDK, in your target's  "Build Settings" tab, is set to "Latest iOS", as the simulator may not show if the target is not being built for the minimum iOS version it supports.