# Add support for iPad Pro 10.5 screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, resolution

I'm developing an iPad app, but when I run it on my iPad Pro 10.5 the status bar is bold, a sign that the app is not optimized for that resolution. How can I add support for the new iPad? I see that other App Store apps (such as Trello for example) work good in full resolution.

I know that there's another question similar to this, but the answers don't really solve the problem. All the 3rd party apps on my iPad are perfect on the screen, but not the one I'm developing. This means that all the other developers have added the launch screen images (not a common practice nowadays) or they found a clean way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add support for 10.5 inch iPad Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392646/how-to-add-support-for-10-5-inch-ipad-pro)